# Looping through array to add ko.computed to each object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm passing my viewmodel from the server as JSON, then adding some functions and observables to the viewmodel before calling `ko.applyBindings()`.

My problem is that I want to loop through an array of objects, and add a computed observable onto each. However, all the computed observables seem to be bound to the last object in my array.

Here is the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.Records().length; i++)
{
    var record = viewModel.Records()[i];

    viewModel.Records()[i].CachedMonthlyAmount = ko.computed(function () {
        var frequencyType = viewModel.GetFrequencyTypeByID(record.SelectedFrequencyTypeID());
        return frequencyType.MonthlyCalculationFactor() * record.Amount();
    });
}
```

I've also created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/952pfm61/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Have a look at this [fix](http://jsfiddle.net/952pfm61/2/). I'll post answer explaining shortly

Comment: @mgasparel check the alternate solution can be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using variables in for loop like that you will need to make a `closure` (ex. use  immediately-invoked function expression **IIFE**) so you can bind the `record` variable within each computed function to a separate unchanging value outside of the computed function.

Simply you need to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.Records().length; i++)
{
    var record = viewModel.Records()[i];

    (function(record){
        record.CachedMonthlyAmount = ko.computed(function () {
            var frequencyType = viewModel.GetFrequencyTypeByID(record.SelectedFrequencyTypeID());
            return frequencyType.MonthlyCalculationFactor() * record.Amount();
        });
    }(record));
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/952pfm61/3/)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Would you mind explaining the last line of the IIFE?

Comment: You're welcome. The last line of the IIFE is just passing a parameter to the IIFE. I will add a simpler example and some references later.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to `ko.computed` defines the target object that will be used to evaluate `this` in the computed callback function. So you can pass your `record` as the second parameter and this will result in correct computed evaluation.

```
for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.Records().length; i++) {
    var record = viewModel.Records()[i];

    viewModel.Records()[i].CachedMonthlyAmount = ko.computed(function () {
        var frequencyType = viewModel.GetFrequencyTypeByID(this.SelectedFrequencyTypeID());
        return frequencyType.MonthlyCalculationFactor() * this.Amount();
    }, record);
}
```

Read more about [managing this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this) from `ko.computed` documentation.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/952pfm61/4/

Answer (score 2):

well much simpler solution would be using `arrayForEach` from [Utility functions](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) in Ko

**Modified piece of code :**

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.Records(),function(item){
 item.CachedMonthlyAmount = ko.computed(function () {
        var frequencyType = viewModel.GetFrequencyTypeByID(item.SelectedFrequencyTypeID());
        return frequencyType.MonthlyCalculationFactor() * item.Amount();
    });
});
```

Using `index` based value assigning i believe those days are gone for good(atmost) . As far as `ko` goes as your are trying to create a dependency via `computed` so (index based assigning) it is not advisable. which indeed possible by using `2nd parameter` of computed function .

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/952pfm61/5/)**